# Accessing a value of a gotten from a function from outside the function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, global-variables

I have the piece of code below and I am having an issue accessing the BMI outside the function as it returns undefined.
The function itself should return the solution of the BMI when the 'calculate' button is clicked. i need to access the BMI value from outside the function scope but it keeps returning undefined. Its already defined outside the function so I'm not sure why it's acting up.
i actually found a workaround to the issue but the resulting code wasn't looking as optimised.

```
const { weight, height } = userInput;

    /**Calculate the BMI and round to two decimal places */
    let BMI;
    const calculateBMI = () => {
        BMI = weight / (height * height);
        console.log(BMI); //logs the value of BMI onClick of the button
        return BMI;
        //let BMIValue = Math.round(BMI * 100) / 100;
        //return BMIValue;
    };

    console.log(BMI); //logs undefined regardless

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <label htmlFor="height">Height:</label>
                <input
                    type="number"
                    name="height"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    value={userInput.height}
                />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label htmlFor="weight">Weight:</label>
                <input
                    type="number"
                    name="weight"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    value={userInput.weight}
                />
            </div>
            <button onClick={calculateBMI}>
                Calculate
            </button>
        </div>
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sync data from your UI after a user interaction then you should go with useState (that's actually an strong use case for it).

So you should try

```
const [BMI, setBMI] = useState();

const calculateBMI = () => {
       currentBMI = weight / (height * height);
       setBMI(currentBMI);
};

console.log(BMI)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. this actually works as desired. i was so preoccupied, i never thought of adding a new state.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here.

The first is that your `console.log()` outside of `calculateBMI()`, while defined after the function, is actually being run before the function, since the function is only called on a click event. Thus it will always log `undefined`.

The second is that react components only re-render on prop or state changes. You'll need to save your `BMI` variable as state in order for the component to re-render and show the updated `BMI`, if that is the purpose of this component.

To debug this and show the BMI value updating after a click try using the `useState` hook and printing the value to the screen with:

```
const [BMI, setBMI] = useState(undefined);

const calculateBMI = () => {
    setBMI(weight / (height * height));
    return BMI;
};

return (
    <div>
        <div>
            <label htmlFor="height">Height:</label>
            <input
                type="number"
                name="height"
                onChange={handleChange}
                value={userInput.height}
            />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label htmlFor="weight">Weight:</label>
            <input
                type="number"
                name="weight"
                onChange={handleChange}
                value={userInput.weight}
            />
        </div>
        <button onClick={calculateBMI}>
            Calculate
        </button>
        {BMI}
    </div>
);
```

Don't forget to import useState at the top of the file, probably with something like

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
```